# Magento translating not working

Tags: magento, caching, translate

I am trying to translate a single line on a product page. 
"Special Price" needs to be changed. 
I found the Mage_Catalog.csv in the app/locale/[language] folder and changed the translation.

I used (translating to Dutch):

- "Special Price:","Aanbieding:"
- "Special Price","Aanbieding"
- "Special Price: %s","Aanbieding: %s"
- "Special Price %s","Aanbieding %s"

After saving & uploading, I cleared all caches: 
Host cache, Magento cache & browser cache.

No result, it works on all other lines, save for this one.

So my next step was to change it on the generated product page, but I can't find the file I need.

Does any of you know?

Comment: Did you try it using 'Offer' instead of 'Special Price'

Comment: What product type do you use?

Comment: 'Offer' is not in the Mage_Catalog.csv file, we use Simple products only at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

price.phtml line 389 +/-

remove variable

```
<span class="price-label">$variable</span>
```

and use

```
<?php echo $this->__('Special Price:') ?>
```

is bug magento, dont translate correct special price =(

Comment: Hi Dexxtz, which price.phtml file might I look into? There are 10 different price.phtml files =-). The files I tried are \default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml and some other default maps. But the files don't have a `<span class="price-label">$variable</span>`. We use Magento 1.8.1

Comment: **edit** on my last comment, I found the `<span class="price-label">$variable</span>` and changed it, but nothing changes. Even after cleaning the Magento cache and browser cache.